# Identificar o campo input vazio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Boa tarde, como faço para deixar o texto (Motivo), input e a frase abaixo vermelhos ao clicar no botão transmitir verificar se o campo está vazio e/ou ao digitar algo muda de cor para verde. Como faço em HTML5 e JS, se tiver em JQuery[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você vai precisar validar o input ao enviar o formulário usando JS, depois estilizar seu HTML usando CSS caso o valor do campo seja inválido. É uma pergunta bastante abrangente, onde exatamente está sua dúvida? O que tentou até agora?

Comment: Coloca o código que vc já tem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um *listener* no `input` que está tentando realizar essa validação, mas gostaria de deixar claro que validações no cliente são só parte do processo, é sempre bom validar os dados no backend.

Mas vamos ao código:

```js
$('#id-do-input').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val()

  if (!value) {
    $(this).removeClass('text-success')
    $(this).addClass('text-error')
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('text-error')
    $(this).addClass('text-success')
  }
})
```

E se quiser fazer essa validação ao pressionar o botão de enviar, é só adicionar o mesmo *listener* acima, porém trocando todas as ocorrências de `$(this)` por `$('#id-do-input')`.